# How to add a custom field to orders in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, custom-fields, shopware

By default you can add custom fields to several entities, however I don’t see the order entity in the list of available entities.

Is it possible to add such a field for order so user can fill it in the checkout process, right before sending the order?

And is it possible to add a field for the order and for each order item individually?

Comment: Right now it is not possible to add custom fields to an order via the admin settings module. But you still can add custom fields via plugin.

Comment: And is it possible to fill the value of the custom field in the checkout page? In sw5 I was doing it by forwarding the response to my controller and then back.

Comment: You may want to use the `CartConvertedEvent` event. This contains the original cart and the order data as array which will be written to the DB. Set the value of your custom field to the order array

Comment: @MichaelT What is the name of the full event? Is it OrderEvents: CartConvertedEvent ?

Comment: no, it is `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\CartConvertedEvent`
Use the `::class` constant to refer to this event in subscribers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example on how to add to add custom fields to order entity:

```
$customFieldSetRepository = $this->container->get('custom_field_set.repository');
    
            $customFieldSetRepository->upsert([
                [
                    'name' => self::FIELD_NAME,
                    // 'global' => true,
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => [
                            'de-DE' => 'Name',
                            'en-GB' => 'Name'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'customFields' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'type' => CustomFieldTypes::DATETIME,
                            'config' => [
                                'type' => 'date',
                                'dateType' => 'date',
                                'label' => [
                                    'de-DE' => 'Date',
                                    'en-GB' => 'Date'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'label' => "Time",
                            'type' => CustomFieldTypes::TEXT,
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => [
                                    'de-DE' => 'name',
                                    'en-GB' => 'name'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'label' => "name",
                            'type' => CustomFieldTypes::INT,
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => [
                                    'de-DE' => 'name',
                                    'en-GB' => 'name'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'relations' => [[
                        'entityName' => 'order'
                    ]],
                ]
            ], $context);
```